# How to track down the exact php files that contains specific html?

Tags: firebug

I have a wordpress site up and running and I like to play around with firebug or web developer (another firefox extension). Whenever I want to change something I can easily inspect that element and change it live in the browser, but consider that wordpress is a modular platform with hundreds of files. So, lets say I press on a  element on the sidebar and I can see that the styles are from style.css file, but how to find out on what exact .php (or .html) this specific  element is embedded?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to read the [WordPress Theme Development Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and familiarize yourself with how the different theme files work together to create a page.  Once you know the basic mechanics, you'll know pretty much exactly which file to go to.

Answer (score 1):

The `php` files operate on server-side, firebug works on client-side so you won't be able to see ALL the `php` files in use from firebug.  On the other hand you can see `javascript`, and `css` files since they are accessible to the client in Firebug.

You can use your `ftp` or `ssh` client to access your server and take a look to the `php` files, by browsing the directories.

Answer (score 0):

"*but how to find out on what exact .php (or .html) this specific element is embedded*"

After much research I don't believe it can be done in Firebug - directly. What worked for me was to inspect an element, note something unique about it (or nearby), then use **FileSeek** to search the theme you are using. If you installed the theme direct from the web, just download a copy to your computer and use **FileSeek** to search it (the program will quickly search for text withing files - and is free).

Hope this helps.